# How to avoid wrapping every method of a Go struct

Tags: go, closures, go-gorm, readability

I have a struct in Go with a [GORM](http://gorm.io/) (Go ORM) database object inside it, alongside a number of other things:

```
type MagicStruct struct {
    Database *gorm.DB
    ... lots of other things
}
```

This struct has dozens of **thread-safe** methods which all rely on its state to do various database-related things:

```
func (m MagicStruct) WriteThingsToDB() error {
    // Do lots of database writes
}

func (m MagicStruct) WriteMoreThingsToDB() error {
    // Do lots of other writes
}

func (m MagicStruct) WriteDifferentThingsToDB() error {
    // Do even more writes. How exciting!
}

... And lots more
```

The problem is, now I need to add transactions to each of these methods.

In GORM, [there are two ways of doing transactions](https://gorm.io/docs/transactions.html):

```
// THE CALLBACK WAY:

db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    // do some database operations in the transaction (use 'tx' from this point, not 'db')
    if err := tx.Create(&Animal{Name: "Giraffe"}).Error; err != nil {
        // return any error will rollback
        return err
    }

    if err := tx.Create(&Animal{Name: "Lion"}).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // returning nil will commit the whole transaction
    return nil
})


// THE SEQUENTIAL WAY:

// begin a transaction
tx := db.Begin()

// do some database operations in the transaction (use 'tx' from this point, not 'db')
tx.Create(...)
...

// rollback the transaction in case of error
tx.Rollback()

// Or commit the transaction
tx.Commit()
```

I'm trying to figure out what I can do with the `MagicStruct` to make *all* of its methods use transactions, without needing to modify each one.

If I try to wrap every use of the functions, instead of modifying the functions themselves:

```
m := MagicStruct{...}
transactionify(m.WriteThingsToDB)
```

Then `transactionify` can't access the contents of `m`, and can't modify the `m` being passed in. If I try to do it sequentially:

```
tx := db.Begin()
m := MagicStruct{
    Database: *tx
}

if err := m.WriteThingsToDB(); err {
    tx.Rollback()
    return
}

if err := m.WriteMoreThingsToDB(); err {
    tx.Rollback()
    return
}
...

tx.Commit()
```

Then it's no longer thread-safe. You can wrap it in a closure:

```
transactionify(m, func(mWithTransaction) {
    mWithTransaction.WriteThingsToDB()
}
```

This actually works, but it's a really ugly way of doing this. Now, every time you want to run one of the `Write...ThingsToDB` functions:

```
// Instead of being able to do this
m.WriteThingsToDB()
m.WriteMoreThingsToDB()
m.WriteDifferentThingsToDB()

// You have to do this, EVERY SINGLE TIME!
transactionify(m, func(mWithTransaction) {
    mWithTransaction.WriteThingsToDB()
}

transactionify(m, func(mWithTransaction) {
    mWithTransaction.WriteMoreThingsToDB()
}

transactionify(m, func(mWithTransaction) {
    mWithTransaction.WriteDifferentThingsToDB()
}
```

Is there a way of solving this problem that maintains thread safety and doesn't require those huge ugly closures every time you want to use the function?

Comment: What about creating a separate struct that wraps all of the methods of `MagicStruct` in a transaction?

Comment: Why is modifying each method a problem?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco There are dozens of methods, and diving into each and every method and wrapping their internals in a transaction is a very big codebase change with broad testing implications, and not in sticking with DRY either

Comment: @NickyLogan How? Also, care to make that an answer?

Comment: "don't repeat yourself" doesn't mean don't reuse necessary features.  It sounds like it was simply an oversight that transactions weren't being used in the first place. Transactions have a specific meaning in sql, i.e., that all the queries within the transactions become an atomic unit.  If you need a group of queries to be atomic, and you don't use transactions, then the implementation is simply wrong.  And anyway, you can't change the way each method works without modifying each one, either manually or with code generation. It may be as simple as starting each w/ `startTxn(); defer endTxn()`